# Invisible Errors in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to figure out why a Wordpress site I moved is doing white screen of death.

Trying to turn on error dumping - but it isn't working. Absolutely nothing is showing up.

Here's sample code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('log_errors', 1);
 ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'groupasa', 'groupasa');

$selected = mysql_select_db("groupasa",$con)

Echo "Test";

?>
```

Comment: View the generated browser code for possible hint or place error reporting code elsewhere where it is not overridden

Comment: Make sure you set your `error_reporting` level as well.

Comment: mysql calls don't output errors. you need to specifically check for error causes by testing for boolean false return values from the various calls. e.g. `$cont = mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());`.

Answer (score 1):

for a fatal error you can turn on errors in php code you have to turn them on in apache or htaccess level. You could also go and look in the error log for the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Right click and check the source of your page, sometimes the html doesn't show the error but it's actually in the code.

Not sure if this is the case but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Echo statement at the very top of the page and then an exit; if the echo displays then your PHP compiler is working fine and you know that the issue is with the code on the page.

next, add the missing semicolon at the end of mysql_select_db line

you could also check your PHP error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Most times you can solve the 'white screen' by going into the database and using the following query to forcibly 'deactivate' all active plugins.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

The *core* of WP is pretty solid, but it's the plugins and garbage that really mucks everything up.